# EWS error code for Non provisioned account

Tags: exchangewebservices

What would be the error code returned if a non provision account user is trying to make EWS operation calls. Will there would be any error in response. If yes, then what type of error-Http error or there would be some error code in response body?

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific error codes although you may need to define what you mean by non provision account as it could mean different things. One example if you try to access a Mailbox before its been provisioned in the Information Store and you try to access the Inbox folder you will get the generalised  ResponseCodeType.ErrorItemNotFound (or ServiceError.ErrorItemNotFound). EWS doesn't force the default folder creation.

Comment: I am trying to ask like if user has created a new account, so firstly autodiscover operation is performed through any mail client application. So is there would be any error in this like- Mailbox doesn't exist or something other or endpoint url would come in response.

Comment: Autodiscover will return  AutodiscoverErrorCode : InvalidUser
  Invalid user mail@domain.com' specified. if the mailbox doesn't exist but the credentials are okay.